# Is tf.recorder way of reading data more efficient than feed to placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm dealing with a huge amount of data in Tensorflow.

One way is to define placeholder and then read my data by my own defined functions outside of the graph, such as a queue and feed a batch every time into the placeholders.

Another way is to use recorder related built-in classes in Tensorflow to directly read data as tensors.

I searched but failed to find any relavant comparison between the two. Does anyone has idea about their advantages and disadvanteges, especially about the efficiency? Which one do you guys prefer when you use tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different methods of reading data in Tensorflow are compared and discussed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data) with more comparison [here](https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/)

`tfrecord` allows to read data in chunks, so you can deal with data that exceed RAM capacity. Also it can be arranged in such way that you read data a separate thread using `tf.Coordinator` and `start_queue_runners`. More information can be found [here](http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html)

Comment: Thank you. I read this before. But it didn't point out pros and cons of different ways.

Comment: Pros of tfrecord are multithreading and reading in chunks. Pros of feed dict and placeholders is simplicity of implementation - good for small data

Comment: If my own defined funcitons is also multithreading. Will there be so much difference when dealing with huge data?

Comment: If you implement multithread reading better than it has been done in Goodle than it may be the case your code runs faster. Nobody can tell apriory. But don't you have troubles with RAM using placeholders if your data is really huge?

Comment: I have added an additional link